# Streams and Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to write a game server, and this is my first time I using sockets.

On both sides (client and server) I want to create two parallel threads:

1) first one is to repeatedly (by while-loop and Thread.sleep()) sending(server) and reading(client) DefaultListModel object to all connected users. I use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream for server and client respectively.

2) second one is to String exchange (for determine which method to invoke). I use BufferedReader and PrintWriter (these threads is main() threads of client and server).

My problem is: all streams are messing up. Client receive DefaultModelList when String is expected and vice versa.

And finally my questions is: is there any way to separate these two processes? Make one stream take only one class and ignore others?

My code:

```
// when server wakes up
//Server:
Thread listChangesChecker = new Thread(new ListUpdater());
    listChangesChecker.start();

// now client starts dialog
Client:
writer.println("old");
writer.flush();
showLoginDialog();

//Server:
String userStart = reader.readLine();
if (userStart.equals("old")) { checkOldPlayer(); }

//Client:
String password = tfPassword.getText();
writer.println(login + " " + password); 
writer.flush();               

//Server:
loginPassword = reader.readLine();
if(userIsOk) {
// first and last time list sends inside main()
objectWriter.writeUnshared(playersLoginList);
}

//Client:  
playersList = (DefaultListModel) objectReader.readObject();
// client second thread starting
Thread t = new Thread(new ListChangeListener());
t.start();
```

Code for server second thread:

```
private class ListUpdater implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                if(!objectWriters.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Sent new model");

                    for (int i = 0; i < objectWriters.size(); i++) {
                        ObjectOutputStream ous = objectWriters.get(i);
                        ous.writeUnshared(playersLoginList);
                        ous.reset();
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for client second thread

```
private class ListChangeListener implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        try {
            DefaultListModel<String> newList;

            while (true) {

                    newList = (DefaultListModel<String>) objectReader.readUnshared();
                    playersList = newList;
                    jList.setModel(playersList);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

Comment: This will never work. Have a think about what is happening on the wire. You can't ensure that each reading thread only sees the data it is intended to see, and you may also have problems wih the writing threads interleaving data. You need to rethink this completely.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with one socket connection?

Comment: _I am trying to write a game server, and this is my first time I using sockets._ Maybe take a few steps back and do something simple before trying to build a house.

Comment: You need to show us code to answer a specific problem.   Yes, it is possible to send two different data types coherently over a single socket.  Yes, you can have two different threads receive these types.  You need to coordinate the resource accesses somehow though.   Post your code.

Comment: @EJP so, using a separate thread, which uses same socket as main() is never works?

Comment: ANy reason you can't just use Netty? Unless it's an assigment for learning, that I can understand. You can refer to its source code though. Have a look here https://github.com/netty/netty I also like this library https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Network

Comment: @Vangel yes, this is my education task)

Comment: put your code up on github or gist and edit your answer to include it. It might help us understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @BadZen added code

Comment: @MichaelBobryashov I've already given you at least one reason *why* it will never work, so asking me *whether* it will ever work is futile.